# NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener does not work

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my Android project I have a very simple Navigation Graph that includes six fragments. The navigation itself works perfectly fine in both directions including the "Back" behaviour. In that project I have a single activity- main activity- where I implement OnDestinationChangedListener. My problem is that my ExamFragment won't open when I click on him. I checked the ids of the fragments and it looks fine. I try to deg it but found nothing. Any idea?

```
MainActivity:

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(SAVE_SWITCH, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        toggleTheme(sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_CHECKED, false));

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppThemeDark);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        findViewById(R.id.imageMenu).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigationView);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        final TextView textTitle = findViewById(R.id.textTitle);

//Here I implement addOnDestinationChangedListener
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller,
                                             @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                textTitle.setText(destination.getLabel());
            }
        });

    }

Navigation.xml:
<navigation
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/menuProfile">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuProfile"
        android:name="ro.ase.proiect_draft.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="Profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuMyJournal"
        android:name="ro.ase.proiect_draft.MyJournalFragment"
        android:label="My Journal"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_journal" />


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuSyllabus"
        android:name="ro.ase.proiect_draft.SyllabusFragment"
        android:label="Syllabus"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_syllabus" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuExam"
        android:name="ro.ase.proiect_draft.ExamFragment"
        android:label="Examens"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_exam" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menuSettings"
        android:name="ro.ase.proiect_draft.SettingsFragment"
        android:label="Settings"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_settings" />

    <fragment
    android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
    android:name="ro.ase.proiect_draft.AboutFragment"
    android:label="About Us"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_about" />


</navigation>

NavigationMenu:

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menuProfile"
    android:icon="@drawable/profile"
    android:title="@string/profile" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuSyllabus"
        android:icon="@drawable/calendar"
        android:title="@string/syllabus"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/menuExamens"
        android:icon="@drawable/exam"
        android:title="@string/examens" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuMyJournal"
        android:icon="@drawable/myjournal"
        android:title="@string/myJournal" />

    <item android:title="@string/others">

  <menu>

    <item android:id="@+id/menuSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings" />

    <item android:id="@+id/menuAbout"
        android:icon="@drawable/about"
        android:title="@string/about" />

  </menu>

</item>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

the ids doesn't match. You have "menuExamens" in the menu and "menuExam" in the navGraph